# Django image compression not working for aws s3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I trying to compressing image before upload on aws s3 bucket. But I am getting this error `This backend doesn't support absolute paths` after add this image compressing code:

```
#image comressing start 
        if self.blog_cover_image:    
                    img = Image.open(self.blog_cover_image.path)  
                    
        img.save(self.blog_cover_image.path,quality=20,optimize=True)
#image compression end
```

**problem 1:**   Image resizing not working after integrating aws S3 bucket.
**problem 2:**  getting this error page after image upload  `NotImplementedError at /blog/edit/hello/ This backend doesn't support absolute paths.` here error details of my terminal

```
"C:\Users\Fdg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 123, in path
    raise NotImplementedError("This backend doesn't support absolute paths.")
NotImplementedError: This backend doesn't support absolute paths.
[27/Dec/2021 23:49:44] "POST /blog/edit/hello/ HTTP/1.1" 500 118419
```

here is my **models.py** for upload images:

```
blog_cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/images/',validators=[validate_file_size,FileExtensionValidator( ['png','jpg'] )],blank=True,null=True) 
#image comressing start 
if self.blog_cover_image:    
            img = Image.open(self.blog_cover_image.path)  
            
img.save(self.blog_cover_image.path,quality=20,optimize=True)
#image compression end
```

Though I am  getting this error but image is uploading on aws S3 bucket. Why I am getting this error and how to overcome it? How to use image compressing in Django for aws s3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

replace the path to url

```
blog_cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/images/',validators= 
[validate_file_size,FileExtensionValidator( ['png','jpg'] 
)],blank=True,null=True) 
#image comressing start 
   if self.blog_cover_image:    
        img = Image.open(self.blog_cover_image.url)  
        
        img.save(self.blog_cover_image.url,quality=20,optimize=True)
```